# Why does photos 'edit in' change image app export behavior?

Tags: photos, images, google-photos, editing

When you open a picture in Pixlr / Snapseed / etc., you are given option of resizing / export the resulting photo.

[image]

However if I 'share' or use gallery 'edit in', I cannot export in Snapseed, and Pixlr is missing image resize on save dialog.

[image]

Why does android differentiate these activities and more importantly can I turn it off?

Really dislike workflow of opening Snapseed first then hunting for a photo I already had open elsewhere. I thought it was a Pixlr issue until Snapseed did similar.

Missing image resize ui from Pixlr:

[image]

Reproduced with Android 7,8, and 9. Google Pixel

Answer (score 1):

I use [Photo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor) and it seems to be able to crop and resize images that other app sends / "shares" to it.

While I don't know exactly why and I don't do any Android development, I think that it could be those two apps provide functionality for "editing only", where the resulting (edited) photo is returned to the handler, in your case, your gallery app, instead of handling by themselves. This could be a possible reason why those apps can't export photos when the photos aren't opened from within the apps.